# Proof of the derivative of $\sin{x}$ is $\cos{x}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, self-learning

I recently learned the proof that the derivative of $\sin x$ is $\cos x$ in Stewarts calculus book. However, in his proof he uses preconceived limit laws such as the sum and product law to evaluate the limit. My confusion is that these limit laws can only be used when the limit exists however we do not know the limit in this case we are trying to evaluate it so how can we use these limit laws must we resort to a geometric proof?

Comment: Giving a valid proof of something like the derivative of $\sin$ is *very* sensitive to your initial definitions. Could you give us your definition of $\sin(x)$? Also, since Stewart's book is not publicly available (and for the completeness of the question besides), could you provide the part of the proof you would like to clarify?

Comment: There are many proofs that amount to something like $$f(x) = \sin(x) \implies f'(x) = \cos(x) \cdot f'(0) \\ g(x) = e^x \implies g'(x) = e^x \cdot g'(0)$$ Is your problem, determining the proof of the existence and value of the derivative at zero?  In this instance, proving $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin(h)}h = 1$? (If so, there are several proofs, but each depends on how you defined the $\sin$ function, so as preferred_anon mentions in their comment, 
 you'd need to specify which definition you are using)

Comment: The product law can be used because we can show *after the fact* that the limits exist. There is no circular argument.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There should not be any problem with limits...
$$\begin{align}\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\sin(x + h) - \sin x}{h} &= \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{2\cos(x + \frac h2)\sin\frac h2}{h} \\&= \lim_{h\to 0} \left[\cos\left(x + \frac h2\right)\cdot\frac{\sin (h/2)}{h/2}\right] \\&\overset*= \lim_{h\to 0}\cos\left(x + \frac h2\right)\cdot\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin (h/2)}{h/2} \\&= \cos x \cdot 1 \\&= \cos x\end{align}$$
*Explanation for* (*): Limit of product is equal to product of limits in this case since both expressions have limits

Comment: If you tell me where are you having a problem, I will try to elaborate on that part.

Comment: So I'm a bit confused on why you  can apply the limit laws such as the limit of a product is the product of the limits to evaluate the limit . The limit product law of works if both the limits exsist however in this case we are not sure whether the limits exsist or not we are trying to evaluate it

Comment: We are certainly sure that those limits exist. These are standard trigonometry limits that can be found thorugh a geometric approach, and that can be found plentyful on the internet. Both VIVID and Hamam make use of those limits

Comment: @Thehomeschooler $f(h) = \cos(x + \frac h2)$ is a continuous function which implies $\lim_{h\to 0}f(h) = f(0) = \cos x$. Also, it is a well-known fact that $\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\sin h}{h} = 1$ some textbooks refer to it as "wonderful limit". It can be proven either with a geometric approach or Sandwich theorem or trivially by L'Hospital's rule (as imranfat mentioned)

Comment: Ah ok thanks a lot this was helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$f(x)=\sin(x)$$
and $ a,h \in \Bbb R$.

$$A(h)=\frac{f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}=$$
$$\frac{\sin(a+h)-\sin(a)}{h}=$$

$$\frac{\sin(a)\cos(h)+\cos(a)\sin(h)-\sin(a)}{h}=$$
$$\frac{\cos(h)-1}{h}\sin(a)+\frac{\sin(h)}{h}\cos(a)$$
and,
$$\lim_{h\to 0}A(h)=0+1.\cos(a)=f'(a)$$

Comment: Could you be more specific about how the limit of $A(h)$ becomes $\cos(a)$?

Comment: In your answer you used the limit laws such as the limit if a product is the product of the limits but the limit has to exsist to be able to use these laws so how can we prove without limit laws?